# Import TensorFlow not working 'could not find dll '

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, windows-installer

When I installed TensorFlow using pip. It worked but when I run the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

It showed me the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\sanu\A programming\python\Python Progams\comparing\balance.py", line 9, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 30, in <module>
    self_check.preload_check()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\platform\self_check.py", line 60, in preload_check
    % " or ".join(missing))
ImportError: Could not find the DLL(s) 'msvcp140_1.dll'. TensorFlow requires that these DLLs be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. You may install these DLLs by downloading "Microsoft C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019" for your platform from this URL: https://support.microsoft.com/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads
```

I went to the manual page [tensorflow.org/install/pip](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) but I could not understand how to install the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @jcoderepo: regarding your edit, software names are just proper nouns. So one installs TensorFlow, not `tensorflow` (this one is not just capitalised, it's camel-cased). The latter is only appropriate if one is specifically referring to console IO.

Comment: @halfer: regarding TensorFlow, I realized it after I have made the edit. But why didn’t you accept my fix on the TensorFlow link? Links like the one posted here must be in the form of hyperlinks.

Comment: @jcoderepo: apologies, I did not see that change. I would have transferred it manually if I had done so, and I'll try to do it now. It was important to reject your edit so that the system can see whether someone needs to advise you about how to improve your edit suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using tensorflow-GPU then you must install Nvidia Cuda for this purpose.

The proper version of Cuda must be installed check the TensorFlow website for the Cuda versions corresponding to different TensorFlow versions.

After proper installation, it should work.

If you are not having GPU in your PC.

**Use normal TensorFlow**

My suggestion is if you are a beginner try google colab.

https://colab.research.google.com/